# UAC on Win Server 2008 causing me a headache!

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008, uac, registrykey

My installer deploys a configuration exe which is used to do some basic configuration on a windows service which is also installed. The exe also needs to create and write some registry keys. On a Windows server 2008 environment these keys can't be created. I have investigated and found that this is an Administrator privilege, and the exe isn't prompting for Admin permissions which are needed under UAC on 2008. I can work around this by right clicking the exe and running as Administrator. This isn't ideal however as its an extra step I need to notify our clients of performing. Are there any other ways of elevating the admin permissions when running the exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a manifest on or with the exe. I can tell you how to embed the manifest using Visual Studio if you let me know what version of that you're using. If you're not using Visual Studio, or you don't build the exe, then you can just put the manifest file in the same folder as the exe and that will work too. In that case the file must be named the same as your exe, with .manifest on the end, eg for foo.exe it's foo.exe.manifest. The content should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Notice the possible values for requestedExecutionLevel are all here in a comment, and this one uses requireAdministrator. Now it will always elevate and therefore work for you.

Comment: Thanks Kate. I've been trying this but still getting the same problem at the moment. Could you as suggested tell me how to embed the manifest within the exe, I'm using visual studio 2008. (Its not picking up the settings in my external manifest file by the looks of it. I renamed the assemblyIdentity name and version property appropriately also fyi)

Comment: An exe is not called foo.config. Either you are not showing extensions, so it's really foo.config.exe, or the exe reads the config file and you need to find out the name of the exe.

Within Visual Studio 2008, for C#: add an Application Manifest to the project. Edit it so you are requesting requireAdministrator (you can copy from the comment.) Then right click the project and choose Properties. On the Application tab drop down Manifest and choose app.manifest. Build.

For VB, just go to the Application tab of your project properties, click UAC settings, change the manifest, and build.

Comment: And in this element: `<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>` it doesn't matter what you put for name. I usually change it but there seems to be no effect on UAC.

Comment: It was a vb app and when i did as you suggested it worked great. Thanks

Comment: sorry, i re-read what i wrote above, to clarify the exe was named Foo rather then Foo.exe. All other files are showing their extensions properly